# JPA OneToMany column name

Tags: jpa, rename, one-to-many

How to set the column name of the foreign key when setting up a one-to-many relationship in JPA?

I would like to change the name of "items_id" to "item_id"

```
@OneToMany
private List<Item> items;
```

I tried the following annotations with no success:

1. @JoinColumn(name="item_id") // join table is not created
2. @Column(name="item_id") // no effect

Comment: You want to customize the join table used to map the association. The annotation to do that is... JoinTable. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to override the mappings of the default values of the join table, so the `@JoinTable` annotation is the one to use. You want to override the name of the inverseJoinColumn from `items_id` to `item_id`:

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="item_id"))
    List<Item> items;
```

---

`@OneToMany` and `@JoinColumn` makes a different mapping, a join table is not created and a foreign key is created in the referenced entity table(in the Item table in your case).

`@Column` is used to override the names for entity attributes, not for relationships.