# JPA OneToOne OneToMany on same class duplicates in List

Tags: java, jpa

I've got the following code:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
private SquadMember commander;

@OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
private SquadMember lieutenant;

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = REMOVE, mappedBy = "squad")
private Set<SquadMember> memberList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

When I add a commander or lieutenant, they end up in the SquadMember table and when I retrieve the memberList from the database the commander and lieutenant are included in the memberList(basically duplicated as they're in the Squad as commander/lieutenant but also as member).

How can I fix this so that the commander / lieutenant never appear in the memberList when retrieved from the database?

Posts I've already looked at but did not find my answer:
[JPA OneToOne and OneToMany on the same entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998788/jpa-onetoone-and-onetomany-on-the-same-entity)

Comment: take a look at your generated model, this link might help [JoinConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700245/jpa-onetomany-column-name)

Comment: So I've been looking into this, but while this solution doesn't cause any duplications, the memberList is somehow disassociated and isn't fetched at all.

Plus I'm getting:
ERROR: update or delete on table "squad" violates foreign key constraint "fks4yt2xg1krcctankbk9at2g7j" on table "squad_member", Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "squad_member".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the piece of code you have put is from the entity "Squad".

In the SquadMember entity you must have three Squad type parameters for the bidirectional mapping to be correct, since if you are going to register a lieutenant and fill in his squad when you only have one parameter, JPA and Hibernate will associate it as being part of the ONE-TO-MANY relationship.

Verify that in the SquadMember entity you have the following:

```
//Relation members with squad
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SQUAD_ID")
private Squad squad;

//Relation bidirectional for lieutenant
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "lieutenant")
private Squad squadLt;

//Relation bidirectional for commander
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "commander")
private Squad squadCm;
```

For example if you need to update commander, use squadCM, etc..